# On Sitecore Item, when we click on Folder tab, The requested document was not found

Tags: sitecore-client

Currently using `Sitecore 10.2 XM` version, when clicking on the folder tab on folder item there is an error showing as below.

[image]

Attaching log stack trace

```
 ManagedPoolThread #8 20:22:56 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=Coveo_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #8 20:22:56 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Precondition failed: The parameter 'p_Communication' must not be null
Parameter name: p_Communication
Source: Coveo.Framework
   at Coveo.Framework.CNL.Precondition.NotNull(Object p_Parameter, String p_ParameterName)
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.AbstractProviderUpdateContext..ctor(ISearchIndexSummary p_IndexSummary, IIndexCommunication p_Communication)
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderUpdateContext..ctor(ISearchIndex p_Index, IIndexCommunication p_Communication)
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderIndex.CreateUpdateContext()
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.ProviderIndex.Update(IEnumerable`1 p_IndexableInfo)
```

Any suggestions here, to fix the issue?

Comment: is it an upgrade? seems like some files are missing

Comment: See if there is anything suspicious in the log. Replace the image with an error log if you found anything.

Comment: This issue is occurring post upgrade and Updated the log trace for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the solution, at least on my instance.

I followed what Dean mentioned in his answer, and I had all that in place but it still didn't work. Then I remembered some time ago there was a Sitecore Support package, where we had to manually delete `xaml` handlers from `Sitecore.config`. We were supposed to do it only on `CD`, but we did it on `CM` as well by accident.

So all I did was add back the custom handlers on `CM's` `Sitecore.config`:

```
<customHandlers>
    ...
    <handler trigger="-/xaml/" handler="sitecore_xaml.ashx"/>
    <handler trigger="~/xaml/" handler="sitecore_xaml.ashx"/>
    ...
</customHandlers>
```

Comment: Yeah I have found the solution but forgot to update here. After adding the xaml entries it has started working.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that you might be missing the file **Folder.xaml.xml** after your upgrade.

I did some digging and it seems that the configuration that defines which control to launch when clicking **Folder** tab is defined here (in core database):

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors/Items/Folder
```

[image]

This in turn calls a url with a `/~xaml/` handler. The xaml handler calls the `Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlPageHandlerFactory` class which searches for the control.

The `/App_Config/XamlSharp.config` defines where to look for the control in the `sources/source/watchers` node:

```
<source type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlFileControlSource,Sitecore.Kernel">
  <watchers hint="list:AddWatcher">
    <watcher type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlFileWatcher,Sitecore.Kernel">
      <folder>/sitecore/shell/Applications</folder>
      <filter>*.xaml.xml</filter>
      <codefilter>*.xaml.xml.cs</codefilter>
      <includesubdirectories>true</includesubdirectories>
    </watcher>
  </watchers>
</source>
```

With that information, you can then locate the specifc file that is being referenced **Folder.xaml.xml**, which you can find in this folder: `sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Editors\Folder`

**Please check that this file is present in your system**

If that does not resolve your issue, please review the definition item in the core database and confirm it is as shown in my image.

Useful reference relating regarding XAML Handler: https://www.markvanaalst.com/blog/daily-tip/using-xaml-controls-outside-the-sitecore-folder/